# python check_output workaround in 2.6

Tags: python, django, git, python-2.6

I'm running on a machine with python 2.6 and no I can't upgrade for now.
I need the `subrpocess.check_output` function but as I've understood this is note defined in 2.6. 
So I've used a [workaround](https://gist.github.com/edufelipe/1027906):

```
try:
    import subprocess

    if "check_output" not in dir( subprocess ): # duck punch it in!
        def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
            r"""Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

            Backported from Python 2.7 as it's implemented as pure python on stdlib.

            >>> check_output(['/usr/bin/python', '--version'])
            Python 2.6.2
            """
            process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
            output, unused_err = process.communicate()
            retcode = process.poll()
            if retcode:
                cmd = kwargs.get("args")
                if cmd is None:
                    cmd = popenargs[0]
                error = subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
                error.output = output
                raise error
            return output

        subprocess.check_output = check_output

    # Git Information
    git_info= {
        "last_tag"      : subprocess.check_output(['git', 'describe', '--always']),
        "last_commit"   : subprocess.check_output(['git', 'log', '-1', '--pretty=format:\'%h (%ci)\'', '--abbrev-commit'])
    }

except Exception, e:
    raise e
else:
    data = git_info

return data
```

I'm using this in conjunction with `Django` + `wsgi`.

The previous piece of code always give me `Command '['git', 'describe', '--always']' returned non-zero exit status 128`.

Now if I run `git describe --always` I get a correct output so I don't think the problem is there.

I have no idea what could cause the problem.

**EDIT:**
If I use the command `subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l'])` or `subprocess.check_output(['pwd'])` things work and from here I've understood that the view called from Django is actually running at `/var/www` being this the DocumentRoot specified in the Apache config file.

The real file is not located under `/var/www` in fact everything works on my local machine where I use the local django dev server. So the git command won't work because there is no git repository under `/var/www`. How can I execute the original `subprocess.check_output(['git', 'describe', '--always'])` from its original path (where the python file is actually located)?

Comment: Does git give you any error text? Try `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` and print the output in an exception handler.

Comment: This is strange code... it unilaterally calls `git` twice on import without concerns for such things as whether the current working directory is a git repo.

Comment: @tdelaney the Exception raised by `stderror` is `-2`, I don't understand, is the git command that return this value? What does it mean exactly?

Comment: use the `cwd` parameter: `subprocess.check_output(['git', 'describe', '--always'], cwd="/path/to/my/repository")`.

Comment: @tdelaney that fixed my problem for me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by passing the cwd argument to check_output as suggested in a comment.

```
def get_git_info():
    git_info = {}

    try:
        import subprocess
        # subprocess.check_output did not exist in 2.6
        if "check_output" not in dir(subprocess): # duck punch it in!
            # workaround/redefinition for the subprocess.check_output() command
            def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
                """ Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.
                Backported from Python 2.7 as it's implemented as pure python on stdlib.
                >>> check_output(['/usr/bin/python', '--version'])
                Python 2.6.2
                """
                process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
                output, unused_err = process.communicate()
                retcode = process.poll()
                if retcode:
                    cmd = kwargs.get("args")
                    if cmd is None:
                        cmd = popenargs[0]
                    error = subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
                    error.output = output
                    raise error
                    # In case we want the error in string format:
                    # stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
                    # raise Exception(stderr)
                return output

            subprocess.check_output = check_output

        # Set on which dir the git command should be invoked
        if os.path.isdir(r'/my/git/dir'):
            cwd = r'/my/git/dir'
        # If using the django local dev server, then it will invoke the command from the dir where this script is located 
        else:
            cwd = None

        # Check that the directory is a git repo:
        # 'git rev-parse' returns a number !=0 if we are in a git repo
        if subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse'], cwd=cwd) != 0:
            # Git Information
            git_info = {
                "last_tag": subprocess.check_output(['git', 'describe', '--always'], cwd=cwd),
                "last_commit": subprocess.check_output(['git', 'log', '-1', '--pretty=format:\'%h (%ci)\'', '--abbrev-commit'], cwd=cwd),
            }

    except Exception, e:
        log.exception('Problem getting git information')
        pass

    # return the git info or an empty dict (defined above)
    return git_info
```